# Terraform detecting changes immediately after apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a fairly simple terraform setup setting up:

- An AWS VPC
- Its default route table, with an endpoint to S3
- A couple of security groups
- Some EC2 instances
- An internal Route53 DNS zone

Now, if I execute `terraform plan` immediately after `terraform apply` from scratch, a bunch of spurious changes are detected. These fall into two categories:

- Empty attributes (tags and `aws_default_route_table.propagating_vgws`), even though they are set explicitly empty in the code
- Two Route53 records that are marked as changed, but show no changes to be applied
- ingress and egress rules in security groups

The first two groups are annoying, but no big deal even if they'd be nice to get rid of.

The last one I'd rather like to get rid of. I think it's related to the fact that I have the rules as separate `aws_security_group_rule` resources rather than inline in the security group resources (because some of them refer to each other mutually). I had a couple of inline rules, but rereading the docs I think that's not allowed, but even removing them doesn't remove this issue.

(Running `terraform apply -refresh-only` makes everything good, but it's really annoying that an apply from a blank slate needs this kind of fixup)

Comment: Could be bug. You can report it on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in Marcin's comment, this seems to have been a bug in Terraform: updgrading the `terraform` executable to the latest version fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Try using Terraform's "count" variable to define multiple security group rules in a single resource. This will help reduce the number of spurious changes Terraform detects.
- If you are using separate security group rules for each rule, you can use the "depends_on" attribute to ensure that the rules are applied in the correct order.
- Finally, if you're still seeing spurious changes, you can try running a "terraform refresh" before running "terraform plan" to ensure that Terraform has the most up-to-date information.